# changing notification settings while listening to music

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, motorola-moto-g2

So that new notifications settings thing on lolipop is really cool and all, but you need to change the volume in order to bring it up. Which is a problem when listening to music, because pressing the volume button brings up music volume, not notification volume. Is there a way to silence/unsilence my phone while listening to music without downloading a third party app?

Comment: This setting is available on CyanogenMod. Are you using a custom or a stock ROM?

Comment: Just stock. Do I really have to boot my phone for this option? Because I would consider it.

Comment: Well, I don't know if there's any other way. Installing custom ROM can be complicated, but it is also rewarding, since you get customization options and various new features, like the ability to change the volume levels independent of whether music is playing or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to go to settings then sounds and notifications, then you can up and down the volume slider to go from vibrate, there's also an option at the top to change the notification type to priority etc.